# Peerjs always shows 'wss://0.peerjs.com/peerjs?key=peerjs&id=peer-ram&token=xxx' failed

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, websocket, p2p, peerjs

I need to implement a Peer 2 Peer chat in my website. most of the links shows [peerjs](https://peerjs.com/) is the most suitable js for P2P chat implementation.I have no `peerjs` API Key, and i need to create own peerid's. Before the implemention, i create two sample html page for create two peers, that set own peerid's. Please see my code below.

**First page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/peerjs/0.3.18/peer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var peer = new Peer('peer-ragesh');
    });
</script>
```

**Second page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="http://cdn.peerjs.com/0.3/peer.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/peerjs/0.3.18/peer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var peer = new Peer('peer-ram');


        var conn = peer.connect('peer-ragesh');
        conn.on('open', function () {
            debugger;
            // Receive messages
            conn.on('data', function (data) {
                console.log('Received', data);
            });

            // Send messages
            conn.send('Hello!');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I run this pages simultaneously in same browser. But it shows the error like below images.

[image]
[image]

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a firewall software in my PC. I forgot to allow the exception for peerjs.

Now it's working. :)

Comment: i have similar error.  can you provide me solution to fix this problem. ? i mean elaborated way with firewall software